# Cannot change textcolor inside a makeup in ConTeXt?

Tags: color, context

I'm  trying to put together a title page makeup in ConTeXt. The background color is set correctly but the text color will not set properly.

```
\definemakeup
    [titlepage]
    [doublesided=no, page=right, headerstate=empty, footerstate=empty, before=\setups{titlepage:setups}]

\startsetups titlepage:setups
    \setupcolors[textcolor=red]
    \setupbackgrounds[page][background=color, backgroundcolor=yellow]
\stopsetups

\starttitlepagemakeup
    \startalignment[center]
        \tfd Some Title
        \blank[2cm]
        \tfa Some Author
    \stopalignment
\stoptitlepagemakeup
```

`\setupcolors[textcolor=red]` does seem to work if it is placed outside the makeup setup.

What have I done wrong with the above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `color` parameter of `\definemakeup` (and don't forget `\start...\stoptext`).

```
\definemakeup
    [titlepage]
    [doublesided=no,
     page=right,
     headerstate=empty,
     footerstate=empty,
     before=\setups{titlepage:setups},
     color=red]

\startsetups titlepage:setups
    %\setupcolors[textcolor=red]
    \setupbackgrounds[page][background=color, backgroundcolor=yellow]
\stopsetups

\starttext

\starttitlepagemakeup
    \startalignment[center]
        \tfd Some Title
        \blank[2cm]
        \tfa Some Author
    \stopalignment
\stoptitlepagemakeup

\stoptext
```

[image]

Comment: Well, that was an easy fix :) But, why doesn't `\setupcolors` work the same way as `\setupbackgrounds` ?